# Resume Tilemill MBTiles export after crash

Tags: tilemill, mbtiles

Is there a way to resume a Tilemill export (MBTiles) after it has crashed?

Today I just got the following crash:

```
 FATAL ERROR: Evacuation Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

This was just a little sample export, but I will need to make a pretty huge export (size of Europe with Zoom Level from 0 - 18) and if that would happen inbetween this export I'd like to know that I don't loose everything, but just a little part and that Tilemill will continue afterwards...

Is there a button for resuming that I am missing?
Or what would be the most reliable solution for this process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long Story Short:

You are screwed with the out of memory issue.  A memory failure is really hard for an application to safely recover from.

> **Edit** --job=[file]   Store state in this file. If it exists, that job will be resumed. (Default: false) [TileMill Command Line options](http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2013/03/08/2013-03-08-automating-tile-generation-with-tilemill/) may provide what you are looking for.  I provided this link in your other [question on failed tiles](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110364/tilemill-re-export-failed-tiles-after-export).

Long Story Long:

- Try looking at your project's `Export -> View Exports` page.  That is the only place to try and resume your export that I can think of.
- You could look at your `tilemill.log` for any more clues as to why your process failed other than the memory issue failure.
- Bad spatial data could cause the render process to fail.
- Make sure that you have your data properly indexed.
- You will want to try the render with TileMill as the only process running on the computer.
- Wrench/configure your project settings.  Try just 1 zoom level.  Also look at the MetaTile setting and try more or less.
- Add more memory or install TileMill and all your project and work files on a solid state drive.

Comment: Hey Greg, Thanks for your help! I already fixed the out of memory problem I think.
Anyway... if we'll export all of europe, and for any reason the export will fail/crash/whatever in the middle, will we be able to resume it? And, there is a -failed file after each export... is there any option to generate only those failed tiles?