# Re-Export failed tiles after export?

Tags: export, tilemill, mbtiles

My Tilemill exports (MBTiles) tend to fail quite often lately... ([Resume Tilemill MBTiles export after crash](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109590/resume-tilemill-mbtiles-export-after-crash) a bounty is waiting for anybody who helps me there btw ;-) ). We kind of solved the problem (at least a bit) by adding more RAM to our machine...

But still... after an export of a quite small sample area I get the following output:

```
[3h 57m 23s] Part(1/1) 100.0000% 411.9k/411.9k @ 79/s | 0s left | ✓ 411.6k ■ 39 □ 0 fail 225
```

So I have 255 failed Tiles. I also have my "log" file cause I started the export adding a `--job` parameter. In the `-failed` log file I can see the coordinates of the failed tiles...

**Is there a way I can tell Tilemill to redo only those failed tiles?**

Comment: Is there no way to tell Tilemill to do an other export?

Answer (score 1):

You could change your bounding box to the area where the failed tiles are located. Then perform another mini-render. I think you'd have to use a tool like [Landez](https://github.com/makinacorpus/landez) to merge the two mbtile databases. [Landez can also render you project's style sheets.](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/render-your-tilemill-stylesheets-with-landez.html)  That may be another way around your problem.

You might want to look at [Tobin Bradley's post on using TileMill at the command prompt.](http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2013/03/08/2013-03-08-automating-tile-generation-with-tilemill/) You don't need the design tool up and running to generate the tiles.  The design tool provides a wonderful lack of information during the render process.

Comment: Don't you know an other way? Do you know what the job-failed file is for?